# binary 'operator *' has too many parameters

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am making a custom matrix class with templates for educational purposes. I want my class
to work in the following way:

```
mat*2; //Works
2*mat; //Should also work
```

For the first case I have the following declaration

```
matrix<T> operator*(const T& a) const;
```

and implemenetation

```
template <typename T>
matrix<T> matrix<T>::operator*(const T& a) const{
//Implementation here
}
```

While for the second case I have to make the implementation as a non member class

```
matrix<T> operator*(T& a, matrix<T>& mat);
```

with the implementation

```
template<typename T>
matrix<T> operator*(T& a, const matrix<T>& mat){
    return mat*a;
}
```

however when I try to compile this I get the following error using MSVC

```
error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters
..\main.cpp(33): error C2678: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a left hand operand of      type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Please add more context. My suspicion is that you placed `matrix<T> operator*(T& a, matrix<T>& mat);` in the class definition.

Comment: Try adding `const` to the parameters of the second function? It's probably unable to pass a non-const reference to the literal `2`.

Comment: I did both of those and it worked. Could you both explain why that is? I am trying to learn more C++ here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter type needs to be either `T` or `T const &`.

A non-const *lvalue* reference can't bind to a literal like `2` (or to a temporary, or a `const` object or reference).

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment: A non-static class method has an implicit first parameter of the class type(the `*this`). The operator you define if placed in the class definition will have three parameters(while a binary `operator*` is supposed to have only 2). If you place the operator declaration in the class definition you need to remove the first parameter and directly work with the class fields.